# Integrate network shares in lens results

Tags: video, 13.04, music, lenses, photo

I have movies, music and photos on a NAS that I have permanently mounted through /etc/fstab. I noticed when I go into the launcher and click on any of the music, photo and video lens, the results do not include NAS results (my guess is because the lenses are looking in /Music, /Pictures and /Videos instead of mounted shares).

Is it possible to modify the lenses to look in the share folder as well to show the results?

Comment: Do you mount your NAS on startup?

Comment: Yes I do, they actually mount before the wi-fi is enabled, causing errors before the welcome screen, but nonetheless are mounted afterwards.